# neo4j cypher json giving http 500 server erro

Tags: json, curl, neo4j

I need to create a few nodes in neo4j and for that I am using json and curl inside my c++ program.

This is the request and response that I get back.

```
About to connect() to localhost port 7474 (#0)
Trying ::1...
Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 7474 (#0)
 POST /db/data/cypher HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:7474
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 4294967295
Expect: 100-continue

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
{
   "params" : {
      "props" : {
         "LocalAsNumber" : 0,
         "NodeDescription" : "10TiMOS-B-4.0.R2 ",
         "NodeId" : "10.227.28.95",
         "NodeName" : "BLR_WAO_SARF7"
      }
   },
   "query" : "CREATE (n:Router { props }) RETRUN n"
}


HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(9.0.5.v20130815)
HTTP error before end of send, stop sending
```

Closing connection 0

I am always getting this **"500 Server Error"**. Is something wrong with the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your query:

```
"CREATE (n:Router { props }) RETRUN n"
```

It should be RETURN:

```
"CREATE (n:Router { props }) RETURN n"
```