# Neo4j Create only if not present query

Tags: neo4j

I am using json to create nodes in noe4j
I have written a small c++ prog to do so using curl and json

Now i have to create around 10000 nodes in neo4j with properties having name and value.
For that i am using props in json with the query as

```
{
   "params" : {
      "props" : {
        [{name : "a", value : 1}, {name : "b", value : 2}......so on]
]
      }
   },
   "query" : "CREATE (n:Router { props }) RETURN n"
}
```

the question is I just want to create that nodes with unique names. If a node is already present with the name as in json props I do not want to create it.
How to write a query for these types of request in neo4j

Comment: Change the query here according to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684369/neo4j-cypher-json-giving-http-500-server-erro

Comment: Changed it and it solved the earlier problem. This is a separate question

Answer (score 2):

Change your query to the following:

```
{
  "params" : {
    "props" : {
      [{name : "a", value : 1}, {name : "b", value : 2}......so on]
    ]
  }
},
   "query" : "FOREACH (router in {props} | MERGE (n:Router {name: router.name}) ON CREATE SET n = router)"
}
```

Basically it iterate the items in your list, check for `name` property if it exist and it case it save a new node

Comment: Thank you for replying. The problem is I do not want to match the complete properties but want to match only the name part and if the node with same name  already exists  then i need to update that node otherwise I need to create it. Please let me know if you need more information regarding this

Comment: Updated the answer for your case

Comment: Make sure that you have a uniqueness constraint on the label, property-name pairs for which you want guaranteed uniqueness. Otherwise `MERGE` is only best-effort, and probably also slower.